# Pre-populated database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Please I need help with this application. I want to embed a database in an android app. My table has 3 columns (_id,Title,Text). The first page of the app shows the titles in a listview, but I want to show the text in another activity when you click an item in the list. Here is how have gone so far. (I found this project online and have modified it.)

```
package com.softeq.prepopdb.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.softeq.android.prepopdb.R;
import com.softeq.prepopdb.dbhelper.ExternalDbOpenHelper;

public class PrepopSqliteDbActivity extends ListActivity {
private static final String DB_NAME = "schymn.sqlite";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Hymns";
private static final String Hymn_ID = "_id";
private static final String Hymn_Title = "Title";
private static final String Hymn_Text = "Text";
    String lyrics;

private SQLiteDatabase database;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> Songs;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();

    fillHymns();
    setUpList();      
}

private void setUpList() {

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Songs));
    listView = getListView();


    /*listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position,long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText().toString(),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
        }
    });*/

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position,long id) {

        }
    });
}


private void fillHymns() {
    Songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor hymnCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                         new String[] 
                                         {Hymn_ID, Hymn_Title,Hymn_Text},
                                         null, null, null, null
                                         , Hymn_Title);
    hymnCursor.moveToFirst();
    if(!hymnCursor.isAfterLast()) {
        do {
            String title = hymnCursor.getString(1);
            lyrics = hymnCursor.getString(2);
            Songs.add(title);
            //Songs.add(lyrics);
        } while (hymnCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    hymnCursor.close();
}
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position,long id) {
                        Log.i("text",lyrics);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is `Log.i("text",lyrics)` supposed to create another activity? Take a look at `startActivity` methods.

Comment: noo,its suppose to log the text associated with the title. I know how to pass extras in intent.

Comment: Are you getting any Exception? Does your Log log anything?

Comment: Yes it logs,but the same item,over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys i was able to solve the problem by creating an adapter and storing the details in key value pairs.